# Cognito User Pools - Cached User ID

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito User Pools for my mobile app. I'm storing user data to DynamoDB and S3 where necessary and using the user ID returned by `getCachedUserID()` to differentiate users.

What exactly is this cached user id (e.g. us-east-1:6fa3bcf6-45bd-4b93-bd68-5cfaffabc123) and can it be used to trace back to specific users in the Cognito user pool? I don't see any ID like this explicitly listed anywhere in the user pool console.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCachedUserId()` returns the Identity pool ID and there currently is not an API that maps Identity Id to the User Pool ID.

A workaround is to create a custom mapping of user pool ID and the identity ID and use it to trace user pool ID from the corresponding cached user ID.